# finding latest trip information from a large data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, amazon-web-services

I have one requirement:

I have a dataframe **"df_input"** having 20M rows which includes trip details. columns are **"vehicle-no", "geolocation","start","end"**.
For each of the vehicle number there are multiple rows each having different geolocation for different trips.

Now I want to create a new dataframe **df_final** which will have only the first record for all of the vehicle-no. How can do that in efficient way?

I used something like below which is taking more than 5 hours to complete:

```
import dfply as dp
from dfply import X
output_df_columns = ["vehicle-no","start", "end", "geolocations"] 
df_final = pd.DataFrame(columns = output_df_columns) #create empty dataframe
unique_vehicle_no = list(df_input["vehicle-no"].unique())
df_input.sort_values(["start"],inplace=True)

for each_vehicle in  unique_vehicle_no:
    df_temp = (df_input >> dp.mask(X.vehicle-no == each_vehicle))
    df_final = df_final.append(df_temp.head(1),ignore_index=True, sort=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work out

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_input=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10,size=(1000,3)),columns=['Geolocation','start','end'])
df_input['vehicle_number']=np.random.randint(100,size=(1000))

print(df_input.shape)
print(df_input['vehicle_number'].nunique())

df_final=df_input.groupby('vehicle_number').apply(lambda x : x.head(1)).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df_final['vehicle_number'].nunique())
print(df_final.shape)
```

Comment: how this ensures that the new dataframe include only  most recent trip for each vehicle number since there is no sort by "start" ?

Comment: Ohh, that was not mentioned in the question. You need to make a small alteration df_final=df_input.groupby('vehicle_number').apply(lambda x : x.sort_values(by='end',ascending=False).head(1)).reset_index(drop=True)